# Differentiable PCA?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, autoencoders, moments, manifold-learning

Is there a differentiable method for dimensionality reduction that is either based on PCA or has the properties of:

- Mathematically or algorithmically defined, e.g. not trained like an ML model or t-sne. EDIT: Another way to state this might be: guaranteed to converge to the optimal solution within a fixed number of steps. (H/T @Sycorax).
- Differentiable, so I can place it in the middle of a NN and get gradients at the input based on error at the output.

Of the course the trivial answer is yes - maxpooling and convolutions are simple forms of dimensionality reduction. Even taking the moments/cumulants of a distribution can be viewed as dimensionality reduction. But I'm looking for something with the power of PCA - something more in line with the spirit of finding linear approximations of the manifold structure of the data.

Auto encoders do perform dimensionality reduction and are differentiable. But they are ML based and therefore require training. I'm trying to cut down the training in my NN so AE's are not a candidate.

Comment: What criteria are you using to distinguish between "training" used for ML and the "algorithmically defined" methods like PCA? Because PCA is typically achieved using iterative numerical procedures which are, in every sense, "training": applying an optimization procedure given some data.

Comment: Thanks for the question Sycorax. I admit I don't know the PCA algorithm in fine detail, but, my understanding was that it was iterative only in the number of dimensions you are trying to reduce to, which is a predetermined, fixed number; and each step is mainly about finding eigenvectors and transforming the distribution to be orthogonal. My definition of ML would be an approximation algorithm that converges asymptotically, implying that the number of steps ends up being a subjective decision the tradeoff of time vs accuracy.

Comment: This may be going too far, but I guess my definition of "not ML" would be a) guaranteed to converge to the optimal solution within b) a fixed number of steps.

Comment: PCA isn't an iterative procedure and differentiability is not a natural or meaningful characteristic of it.  How one *computes* the PCA may be done iteratively, but at bottom it's a linear algebraic matrix decomposition.  Please, then, clarify what you mean by "differentiable method for dimensionality reduction."

Comment: I might be necro-commenting right now, but have you actually found any differentiable PCA versions or alternatives? A cheap and meaningful deterministic differential bottleneck can be of much use to NNs!

Comment: I never did. I had tried to get tf.transform to do it and didn't get very far. I suspect it's possible since tf.linalg.eigenvals does exist and is differentiable. How you deal with differentiating the sorting and picking of the biggest eigenvals is probably solvable the same way as max and max pool. I'll try to implement this sometime.